# How to embed PKCS7/.p7s into a PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a .p7s file and trying to embed into a PDF, how to do this with iText?

I need help

thanks & Regards
Don

Comment: I assume you don't want to embed that file as a generic file attachment but you want to embed it to get an integrated signature. In that case one question first: what does that p7s sign? The whole pdf? In that case you're already on the wrong track, for integrated signatures you need to first prepare the pdf (by setting the value of a signature AcroForm form field value to a structure with a placeholder), then create a p7s signing that prepared pdf except the placeholder, and then embed that p7s into the placeholder.

Comment: Thank you, let me more detail:
We are in Digital Signature project, we use EJBCA DSS for client side hashing, EJBCA DSS returns a p7s string and we need to concat it into a PDF, there is no signature field inside the PDF.. any comment?

Comment: As said above, for integrated pdf signatures, the pdf needs to be prepared and the hash must be calculated for the prepared pdf minus the placeholder therein. The p7s signature container can then be injected into this prepared pdf or into the pdf prepared *identically* again. If you start by simply hashing the original pdf without preparing it, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Have you updated your work flow to match these requirements and still need help integrating the signature into the prepared PDF?

Comment: mkl thank you, I have 3 signers in a pdf, the pdf have to be signed sequentialy start from the 1st signer to the 3rd signer, my question: firstly I have to prepare the pdf without any signature place holder and calculate the hash and for the 2nd signer I have to prepare the pdf that already signed by the 1st signer and calculate the hash and after the 2nd signer signed the pdf, I have to prepare the pdf that already signed by the 1st & 2nd signer and calculate the hash for the 3rd signer, or I can prepare the pdf without any signature placeholder and calculate the hash for all of 3 signers?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096), in particular [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKdYw.jpg). You'll see that the first signature is part of the signed bytes of the second and third signature, and the second signature is part of the signed bytes of the third signature. Thus, you cannot calculate the hash for the second signature before the first signature is embedded, and you cannot calculate the hash for the third signature before the first two signatures are embedded.

Comment: @Mkl,
found in iTextPdf.com & try DefferedSigning.cs

For the 1st signer, I did as follow:

I call app.EmptySignature for the original signature and ten call app.CreateSignature, it works as expected and I think I'm also able to get p7s hash from app.CreateSignature, Please CMIIW, and the 1st signer is shown in the PDF.

For the 2nd signer, I did as follow:
I call app.EmptySignature by passing the PDF that's already signed by the 1st signer and also call app.CreateSignature but I got the 1st signer override with 2nd signer, so there are 2 2nd signers in the PDF. 

What did I miss?

Comment: Mkl..I figured it out :)
I have to add .UseAppendMode() for StampingProperties() in EmptySignature method..

now I am trying to use PKCS 7 to sign ..
could you please let me know what should I consider to embed p7s for pdf signing?

Comment: @Mkl

How do I get PKCS 7 byte[] after signer.SignExternalContainer(external, 8192); ?

Comment: Please update your question to represent the state of your approach (there is an [edit] link underneath it), it is difficult to follow from multiple comments. Code in comments is in particular difficult to read while you can format it decently in the question itself (indent by at least 4 spaces).

Comment: See. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61574699/how-to-generate-p7s-byte-array-of-empty-signature-field-in-itext-7